# Can't update model in Rails 4 without selecting updated_at attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm upgrading from rails 3.2.13 to 4 and ran into an issue updating models. I'm trying to update just a single attribute on a model where I have only the id, I also want validations and callbacks. This worked fine in rails 3 but I'm having trouble in rails 4.

In rails 4 if I do:

```
user = User.select(:id).first
user.first_name = 'name'
user.save!
```

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `type_cast' for nil:NilClass
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:10:in `type_cast'
```

If I run the same code in rails 3 first_name is updated and updated_at is updated with the current_time.

If in rails 4 I run:

```
user = User.select(:id, :updated_at).first
user.first_name = 'name'
user.save!
```

Everything works fine.

I assume the error is caused by the fact that the updated_at column is not there, but it shouldn't need to be. In many of my queries I select only the id for speed. Rails 3 handled this perfectly. I also tried this using update_attributes but I received the same error. It works when I use update_column but then it skips validation and callbacks which I want.

I'm not sure why this is happening in rails 4 or how to get around without explicitly calling validation and callbacks after update_column or selecting the updated_at attribute which I shouldn't need to do.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into that too.

The problem seems to be that updated_at is not loaded.
When you update_attribute, it will try to update `updated_at` too.
It tries to find the way to type cast that column but somewhere the column is not loaded because not selected.

For me this is a bug in Rails.
But maybe it is intended to be like that.

I will open an issue on rails/rails on GitHub as soon as I reproduced the bug in a standalone ruby file. Will update this post with the link.

Comment: I got the error with Rails 4.1.6 and only when using PostgreSQL, not MySQL (I'm switching DBs). With MySQL it worked well with everything exactly the same. I just added updated_at to my selects to keep working with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

`User.select(:id).first` will return a User with only an `:id`. Has this changed since Rails 3?

**Try using**

```
 User.find(id).update_attribute(:first_name, 'Name')
```

Also, you're lucky those `User`s weren't saving because if they were, it would have looked like:

```
User
 id: 1
 first_name: "John"
```

and no additional information would have been saved.

Comment: In both rails 3 and 4 User.select(:id).first returns a user object with just an id attribute. If I execute the code I outlined above in rails 3 the query when I save is UPDATE "users" SET "first_name" = name, "updated_at" = '2014-02-28 01:17:30.448205' WHERE "users"."id" = 1                    This is exactly what I want but it doesn't work in rails 4.

Comment: also, update_attribute calls save, so all of your callbacks should still be run.

Comment: did you switch to using .find instead of .select ?

Comment: user = User.order(:updated_at).first.update_attribute(:name, 'name')