# How are view helpers available in the controllers?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have come across a bit of confusion regarding the use of view helpers controllers. The kind of scenario I have is:

**session_helper.rb**:

```
module SessionsHelper

  # logs in the given user.

  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id]=user.id
  end
```

**sessions_controller.rb:**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to root_url()
  end
```

Now, as per the documentation that I have read, it mentions that helpers are used in views, to reduce the amount of coding to be done there.

My question is: how I am able to use the `log_in` and `log_out` methods defined in the `session_helper` in my controller?

If anyone can clear me on this concept would be very much helpful.

Comment: Why are you downvoting if you can't help people ? . Have some humanity and grow up please . helping people won't do any harm to you.

Comment: Just format your code better, to make it understandable

Comment: @SergioTulentsev :   done editing the code , i hope its readable now and you can upvote it again .

Comment: @huzefabiyawarwala: hm? I don't see any readability improvement. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22082187/cant-update-model-in-rails-4-without-selecting-updated-at-attribute?rq=1) is a post with readable code. Yours doesn't look like it at all.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : done editing again , have a look at it.

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Comment: my problem is more important then your so called english punctuation . Grow up please and learn to be a human first before downvoting people's questions.

Comment: Please use English punctuation when writing in English.

Comment: @halfer : Thank you sir for editing my question .

Comment: No problem. In Markdown, if you want a code block inside an ordered list, you have to indent twice (8 spaces instead of 4).

Comment: @halfer : Ok sir . I will make sure this mistake doesn't happen next time

Comment: @Drenmi : Thank you sir . I have learned many things from your edits.

Comment: No problems @huzefabiyawarwala! Don't be discouraged to ask questions. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer on your question:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.log_in(user)
```

But, it's better to place those methods in the controller.

Comment: But i am following the Ruby on Rails 3rd edition and according to that book , the log_in etc methods are defined in the session_helper files. So is there any specific reason behind this ?

Comment: Give me a link, please

Comment: As you can see, Michael `include SessionsHelper` to his `ApplicationController`: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out#sec-logging_in But this is bad way in my opinion.

Comment: got it . thank you for helping. i am cleared now with whole scenario. :)

Comment: @asiniy, you can also invoke: view_context.log_in(user) in your controller.